# Pygame: How do I apply Separating Axis Theorem (SAT) to Rotating Squares?

Tags: python, vector, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I don't want the code (I really do want the code), but can someone explain to me how I can create the diagonal line to see if there's a gap? I know we have to use vectors, but I don't know how to do that using python

Comment: This is likely too broad, please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Comment: Is it bad to have a broad question? This one isn't that broad either; there's only one solution to it, especially when done through pygame

Comment: Had a quick google of it, i understand basic concept but not the math for how to implement it. Especially in python. It looks like you need to know the vertices of square, which isnt hard until you rotate the square as in pygame, when you rotate, its makes a rotated square inside a square surface, so don't know how to get vertices once rotated unless you can mathematically work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, using the logic of Separating Axis Theorem that if you cant draw a line in between 2 squares then they are overlapping and colliding. I made something close, its not perfect but its close, I also haven't accounted for rotation of squares but if you find a way to find the vertices/corners of the square, then this could easily work. The way i did it was that i turned the squares into lines and drew a line directly in the middle of the squares and at the normal of the line in between the squares, its a bit confusing but it makes sense once you see it. I then used [line intersecting maths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Intersection_of_two_lines) to find if they intersect.

[image: pygame image]

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import Vector2

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

#check if 2 lines are intersecting
def LineIntersect(line1, line2):
    #the math is from wikipedia
    x1 = line1[0].x
    y1 = line1[0].y
    x2 = line1[1].x
    y2 = line1[1].y

    x3 = line2[0].x
    y3 = line2[0].y
    x4 = line2[1].x
    y4 = line2[1].y

    den = (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4)
    if den == 0:
        return 
    t = ((x1 - x3) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y3) * (x3 - x4)) / den

    u = -((x1 - x2) * (y1 - y3) - (y1 - y2) * (x1 - x3)) / den

    if t > 0 and t < 1 and u > 0 and u < 1:
        pt = Vector2()
        pt.x = x1 + t * (x2 - x1)
        pt.y = y1 + t * (y2 - y1)
        return pt
    return



#class for sqaure
class square:
    def __init__(self,x,y,w):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.centerx = self.x + w//2
        self.centery = self.y + w//2
        self.col = (255,0,0)

    def Draw(self, outline = False):
        if outline:
            self.Outline()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.col,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.w))

    def Outline(self):
        for point1, point2 in self.Lines():
            pygame.draw.line(screen,sqr2.col,point1,point2,1)         

    #get the lines that make up the square, the outline/perameter
    def Lines(self):
        lines = []
        lines.append((Vector2(self.x,self.y),Vector2(self.x+self.w,self.y)))
        lines.append((Vector2(self.x,self.y),Vector2(self.x,self.y + self.w)))
        lines.append((Vector2(self.x + self.w,self.y + self.w),Vector2(self.x+self.w,self.y)))
        lines.append((Vector2(self.x + self.w,self.y + self.w),Vector2(self.x,self.y + self.w)))
        return lines

#draw a line inbetween the 2 squares
def DrawLineInBetween():
    #draw a line between the 2 squares, get gradient
    #to avoid divide by zero
    if abs(sqr1.x - sqr2.x) == 0:
        gradient = "infinity"
    else:
        #rise over run
        #left - right = run
        left = sqr1 if sqr1.x < sqr2.x else sqr2
        right = sqr1 if left == sqr2 else sqr2
        gradient = ((left.y - right.y)/abs(sqr1.x - sqr2.x))
    #print("gradient:",gradient)

    #get the middle point between the centers of the squares
    middle = (max(sqr1.x + sqr1.w//2, sqr2.x + sqr2.w//2) - abs(sqr1.x - sqr2.x)//2,
              max(sqr1.y + sqr1.w//2, sqr2.y + sqr2.w//2) - abs(sqr1.y - sqr2.y)//2)
    #to avoid divide by 0
    if gradient == 0:
        point1 = Vector2(middle[0], middle[1] + 100)
        point2 = Vector2(middle[0], middle[1] - 100)
    elif gradient == "infinity":
        point1 = Vector2(middle[0] - 100, middle[1])
        point2 = Vector2(middle[0] + 100, middle[1])        
    else:
        #get normal of line
        gradient = -1/gradient
        #print("normal:",gradient)

        point1 = Vector2(middle[0] + 100, middle[1] + int(-100 * gradient))
        point2 = Vector2(middle[0] - 100, middle[1] + int(100 * gradient))
        #print(point1)
        #print(point2)
        #print(middle)

    pygame.draw.line(screen,(0,255,0),point1,point2,1)

    line = (point1, point2)
    return line


sqr1 = square(100,100,50)
sqr2 = square(200,100,50)

Clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
key = ""

while running:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    sqr1.Draw(outline=True)
    sqr2.Draw()
    line = DrawLineInBetween()

    for sqr_line in sqr1.Lines():
        pt = LineIntersect(line,sqr_line)
        if pt:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen,(0,255,255),(int(pt.x),int(pt.y)),5)

    if key == "s":
        sqr1.y += 1
    elif key == "w":
        sqr1.y -= 1
    if key == "d":
        sqr1.x += 1
    if key == "a":
        sqr1.x -= 1

    pygame.display.update()
    Clock.tick(60)

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print(e.pos)
        if e.type == KEYDOWN:
            key = e.unicode
        if e.type == KEYUP:
            key = ""
```

---

doing rotating squares:
added rotation variable in square class, i used [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/86784) to find the corners of the square, then once i have the corners, used the line intersetion.

Here is new class:

```
#class for sqaure
class square:
    def __init__(self,x,y,w):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.centerx = self.x + w//2
        self.centery = self.y + w//2
        self.col = (255,0,0)
        self.rotation_angle = 0

    def Draw(self, outline = False):
        if outline:
            self.Outline()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.col,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.w))

    #this used the normal coordinate of an unrotated square to find new coordinates of rotated sqaure
    def GetCorner(self,tempX,tempY):
        angle = math.radians(self.rotation_angle)
        rotatedX = tempX*math.cos(angle) - tempY*math.sin(angle);
        rotatedY = tempX*math.sin(angle) + tempY*math.cos(angle);   

        x = rotatedX + self.centerx;
        y = rotatedY + self.centery;        

        return Vector2(x,y)      

    def Outline(self):
        for point1, point2 in self.Lines():
            pygame.draw.line(screen,sqr2.col,point1,point2,1)         

    #new lines method, only changed to GetCorner()
    def Lines(self):
        lines = []
        top_left = self.GetCorner(self.x - self.centerx, self.y - self.centery)
        top_right = self.GetCorner(self.x + self.w - self.centerx, self.y - self.centery)
        bottom_left = self.GetCorner(self.x - self.centerx, self.y + self.w - self.centery)
        bottom_right = self.GetCorner(self.x + self.w - self.centerx, self.y + self.w - self.centery)

        lines.append((top_left,top_right))
        lines.append((top_left,bottom_left))
        lines.append((bottom_right,top_right))
        lines.append((bottom_right,bottom_left))
        return lines

    #chnaged to this as rotation rotates around center, so need to update both x and centerx
    def Move(self,x =None, y = None):
        if x:
            self.x += x
            self.centerx += x
        if y:
            self.y += y
            self.centery += y

    #get the lines that make up the square, the outline/perameter
    #def Lines(self):
        #lines = []
        #lines.append((Vector2(self.x,self.y),Vector2(self.x+self.w,self.y)))
        #lines.append((Vector2(self.x,self.y),Vector2(self.x,self.y + self.w)))
        #lines.append((Vector2(self.x + self.w,self.y + self.w),Vector2(self.x+self.w,self.y)))
        #lines.append((Vector2(self.x + self.w,self.y + self.w),Vector2(self.x,self.y + self.w)))
        #return lines
```

Comment: Thank you so much for doing research on the topic. I would upvote you but my reputation is too low. If we were to draw a line between rotated objects, then I believe we could use '[object].[top/left/bottom/right]' to identify the coordinate of the max/min. I works for my code, but I'm not sure how to use that for SAT

Comment: If you can find the coords of corners, then you just need to change the `square.lines()` method to return those points.

Comment: @BenjaminLuo I found a way to use rotating squares. Must say, did enjoy doing this

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to revisit this post and spend so much time finding an answer (perhaps even more time than me). I tried for hours but failed and submitted the assignment without seeing this. Nonetheless, thank you for fulfilling my curiosity on the logic behind SAT collisions